# Finding a system of linear equations whose solution space is $\langle a_1,a_2,a_3\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

I am trying to do a problem for linear algebra and I have run into a problem I have no idea how to solve. The problem is:

> Find a system of linear equations whose solution space is the subspace $\langle a_1,a_2,a_3\rangle$ of $\mathbb R^5$, where 
>   $$a_1=(1,-1,0,1,-1);\ a_2=(1,-1,-1,0,1);\ a_3=(1,0,1,-1,1).$$

I am not even sure what topic this is. Could someone provide me with a method to follow or even the name of the topic so I can search for some online resources to learn a method.

Comment: $a_1,a_2,a_3$ :  are these the basis vectors of the subspace which is given to you?

Comment: Find two linearly independent $a_4,a_5$ that are orthogonal to the $a_1,...,a_3$. Then $x$ is in the subspace above **iff** $a_4^T x = 0 $ and $a_5^T x = 0$.